# How do you Find & Replace only in specific Styles in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, subtitles

I have a document with sub-sections and text. The sub-titles for each sub-section starts with a number. I want to remove this number.

I know searching for `^#` and replacing with 'blank' removes all numbers in the document.

I now want to perform this replacement procedure only when the Style is `Heading 1` or `Heading 2` and not when it is `Normal`, such that I end up with sub-titles without numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is available from the **Find and Replace** window.

[image]

You will need to do this for each heading style you want to replace.

Comment: Including the screenshot for the Find & Replace dialog where you filter by style might be useful here.